# ASYNC update to label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I realize I may be pointed to different articles but my head is spinning on the right way to do this. I tried some code to simply display the current time, then display the finish load time and then display the async label 5 seconds later. I currently have a website that does a COUNT SQL script on the homepage that displays the total rows in a label and its pausing the home page until it's complete. Obviously for performance reasons I need to get rid of this. I tried simply putting some script inside an update panel and nope.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">
    First Load is <% =GetTime()%>.

</asp:Label>
    <script runat="server">
    protected String GetTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <script runat="server">
                protected String GetAsyncTime()
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                return DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
            </script>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPanel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            Async time is <% =GetAsyncTime()%>.

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
</form>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label">
    Last Load is <% =GetTime()%>.

</asp:Label>
```

Comment: what doesn't work? Is the label not displaying?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. Even though I'm attempting to load lblPanel Asynchrounously so that the other 2 labels can load in the meantime it freezes on lblPanel and prevents the rest of the page from loading. Here's the results of the previous code:

Comment: First Load is 12/25/2014 3:10:26 PM.
Label Async time is 12/25/2014 3:10:31 PM.
Last Load is 12/25/2014 3:10:31 PM.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".